# php get the value of select input passing it on as variable for table name query

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the value of the select box and passing on as a variable to be used as a table name for a query but it came up empty. I couldn't figure out the causes of it. Any chap/gal out there know the issue with the code below?

```
<select class="form-control" name="properties" type="text" class="form-control" required>
  <?php
    $prop = $_GET['properties'];
    $sql = "SELECT `id`
            FROM '".$prop."' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $result = $DB_CON_C->query($sql);
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you saying your query comes up empty? As you have it, you have to do a `while()` then echo the options with the returned results otherwise nothing is really happening with your script at this point.

Comment: I have the while() included but forgot to include in my post.